# c# sockets read data and then reply

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using the following code (built from answers to my previous questions on SO):

```
public void Start()
{
    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9030);
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    StartAccept();
}

private void StartAccept()
{        
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, listener);            
}

private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult res)
{
    StartAccept();
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

    using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
    {
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = ns.Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)) != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, readCount));
        }

        // Do work

        // Test reply
        Byte[] replyData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        ns.Write(replyData, 0, replyData.Length);
        ns.Flush();
        ns.Close();
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

The line "Do work" represents where I will do the required processing for my client.

However I can't see how to use this code to read the client's data and then reply to it. When using this code I can read perfectly what is sent by my client, however once that occurs the client locks up and eventually complains that the connection was terminated. It does not receive my reply.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the client listening for the reply? Are you sure that you are not closing the stream on the client side after writing to the server?

Comment: The client uses a System.Net.Sockets.Socket. It uses the Send() method to send a string of data. It then straight away defines a string[] to hold received data and calls Receive() on the same socket to read the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first of all, you are mixing asynchronous calls (`BeginAcceptTcpClient`) and synchronous (`Read` and `Write`) calls. That completely kills the purpose of *asynchronous* code. Second, maybe this is why your socket gets closed ? Performing a sync op on an async socket. I'm not sure, but without the client code it's impossible to tell.

Anyway, this is NOT how you build an asynchronous, multi-client server.

Here is a fully asynchronous server implementation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Comment: -1. There are no sync or async sockets. Just sync and async methods performing the IO. You can mix without any problems. This solution is perfectly fine to use instead of creating one thread per client (which is done thanks to the .Net thread pool)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use a length byte to alloc your buffer. ReceiveBufferSize could be called multiple times, i think there is no gurantee you receive everything in one block.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood how `Read` works. It blocks until something is received from the other end point. The only time it returns 0 is when the other side have disconnected, hence you will continue reading until the other side disconnects.

When using TCP you need to know when a message ends. You can do that either by sending the message length first as a header or by using a suffix (as a line feed) after each message. Then you should keep reading until the complete message has arrived.